# Escrever Html usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estava estudando alguns plugins jquery e percebi que para criar o html, o programador escreveu cada linha em um array e ao final usou o join:

```js
var tpl = [
  '<div class="popover clockpicker-popover">',
   '<div class="arrow"></div>',
   '<div class="popover-title">',
    '<span class="clockpicker-span-hours text-primary"></span>',
    ' : ',
    '<span class="clockpicker-span-minutes"></span>',
    '<span class="clockpicker-span-am-pm"></span>',
   '</div>',
   '<div class="popover-content">',
    '<div class="clockpicker-plate">',
     '<div class="clockpicker-canvas"></div>',
     '<div class="clockpicker-dial clockpicker-hours"></div>',
     '<div class="clockpicker-dial clockpicker-minutes clockpicker-dial-out"></div>',
    '</div>',
    '<span class="clockpicker-am-pm-block">',
    '</span>',
   '</div>',
  '</div>'
 ].join('');
```

Alguém, com experiência, sabe porque escrever dessa forma, ou seja, sem usar uma string e concatenar cada linha?

```js
var tpl = '<div class="popover clockpicker-popover">'+
   '<div class="arrow"></div>'+
   '<div class="popover-title">'+
    '<span class="clockpicker-span-hours text-primary"></span>'+
    ' : '+
    '<span class="clockpicker-span-minutes"></span>'+
    '<span class="clockpicker-span-am-pm"></span>'+
   '</div>'+
   '<div class="popover-content">'+
    '<div class="clockpicker-plate">'+
     '<div class="clockpicker-canvas"></div>'+
     '<div class="clockpicker-dial clockpicker-hours"></div>'+
     '<div class="clockpicker-dial clockpicker-minutes clockpicker-dial-out"></div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<span class="clockpicker-am-pm-block">'+
    '</span>'+
   '</div>'+
  '</div>';
```

Comment: Defina "melhor".

Comment: Template strings do ECMA6 no quesito "programar" é muito bom, porém não sei quanto ao desempenho e compatibilidade ainda não é tão amplo.

Comment: A dúvida é quanto ao desempenho mesmo, corrigir o "melhor"

Comment: No Ecma6 tem o template string segue link: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Não conhecia este template string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre usar `join` ou concatenação, concatenar apresenta um melhor desempenho, porém a escrita do código pode ser mais massante, principalmente ao se usar `'` com `"` e quando há muitas linhas.

[Nesse](https://jsperf.com/join-vs-concat-in-string) teste, localmente, a concatenção correu *12.497* vezes em *0.083* segundos contra *11.144* em *0.087* segundos com `join`.

[Nesse](https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-template-strings) outro, localmente, a concatenção correu *12.703* vezes em *0.086* segundos contra *12.875* em *0.080* segundos com [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

Particularmente estou preferindo usar template string quando preciso escrever *HTML* no javascript. Subjetivamente ele se parece melhor e mais fácil de se ler, justamente para strings multi-linhas e string contendo `'` e `"`. E o mais interessante sobre ele são as [Tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Tagged_template_strings), que da esse poder:

```
let conta = {numero: '9999-9'};   
tag `Minha conta é ${conta.numero}.`
```

**Compatibilidade com navegadores**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.